# Java WebDAV client side library

Tags: java, client-side, webdav

What Java WebDAV client side library could you recommend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you looked at [Jackrabbit's](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/components/jackrabbit-webdav-library.html)?

Comment: Have you used it yourself? I would like to hear any feedback…

Comment: Yes. Compared to just using the Apache commons HTTP client, it helps with constructing and parsing the messages.

Answer (score 23):

I've recently created one that is quite easy to use:

https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine

Answer (score 7):

OK I'm a bit late, but you really should check out the [milton webdav server](http://milton.io/) project. Its open source (apache2), mature and is actively maintained.

Its designed to allow any backend implementation to be hooked up to webdav, and many users have reported implementing it in under 4 hours for existing applications.

It supports all the usual webdav stuff like locking, custom properties, digest/basic authentication, etc. It also supports caldav and integrated with apache FTP so you get 2 protocols for the price of one!

Milton ships with a servlet and a spring controller, and it can run independently of a web container.

Milton also has a nice little webdav client library, which is ideal for desktop apps due to its observer support.

Answer (score 3):

I used the client library provided by the **Jakarta Slide** project for a software that I developed about 2 years ago, and it worked fine. Now, visiting the [site](http://jakarta.apache.org/slide/), I see that the project is no longer active for lack of developers. But the client library should still be a good choice for you. Anyway, I don't see many alternatives out there.

Comment: alexmeia, thanks for your answer, but this library is not good chose  because of retirement.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdavclient4j/ is based on the retired Apache Jakarta Slide project's Java webdav client, and includes the VFS WebDAV provider. It is packaged with HttpClient 3.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Try to esteem about them here: http://www.webdavsystem.com/javaserver

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Sardine?

https://code.google.com/p/sardine/

https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine

Latest release 5.3 - August 2013  and available at Maven Central:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.lookfirst/sardine/5.3