# How to have my webdav client/server go faster?

Tags: java, performance, glassfish, webdav

I'm using WebDaV as a file exchange solution between a client and a server I'm both developping.

Client uses [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/), and server uses [Glassfish 3 WebDAV servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beaft.html#gezcx). That seems sensible choices, no ?

Anyway, each time I write a file to server (using as an example [`FileObject#copyFrom(...)`](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileObject.html#copyFrom%28org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject,%20org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSelector%29)), I find the operation to perform incredibly slowly (100 s for a one-line file write when both client and server run on same machine).

So, do you see comparable delays ? And is there anything that can be done to improve those ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like current implementation of commons-vfs WebDAV (which relies upon an old version of Jackrabbit webdav) parses all DTDs it receives alongside HTTP response. For that, it must grab them where they reside on the web. This is obviously not the most efficient way to do.

To fix that, I've started a [sardine](http://code.google.com/p/sardine/)-backed (found from [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091571/15619)) implementation of commons-vfs-webdav, which reveals to be way faster (that 100 s. test now taks 0.233 s.)